# How to do Sum in Diesel Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

Reproduction project: https://github.com/Jasperav/sumdieselrust

Problem is in method `money_donated`. I have a column 'donated' in table 'donation'. I want to sum up all the values in the db and return the result as a value over JSON. However, I am having trouble with all the types in Diesel, I don't understand how I can do a simple sum.

The compile error I get is:

> ^^^^^ the trait
>   `diesel::deserialize::FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Numeric>,
>   diesel::pg::Pg>` is not implemented for `i32`

for this line:

```
// The rounding is not important for JSON, so an i32 is fine to use
let amount: i32 = donation.select(sum(donated)).first(&c).unwrap();
```

In the project I was trying to implemented the trait `FromSql` and then I thought to myself that all this work is too much for something simple like this, so maybe I am missing the point and doing too much work.

I read the docs here: https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/dsl/fn.sum.html as well as this question: https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/210. I still can not figure it out how to make it work.

Comment: did you fixed this problem? @J. Doe